# The member with identity 'PmData.SafetyRequirement_Assets' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net5

I am trying to update an record in my system.  Everything on the model saves great, except any of my many to many type relationships on the form.  When I get to those in my model it gives me the error. "The member with identity 'PmData.SafetyRequirement_Assets' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity".  I've read over some of the other answers but I do not have any triggers on my database, and I've gone through several changes in my model based on other suggestions and it doesn't seem to change anything.  The project is in vNext.

Here is my first model

```
public partial class Asset : DataModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string SystemFunction { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2048)]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public bool IsSystem { get; set; }
    public bool IsGrouping { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string FieldTag { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Building")]
    public int? BuildingId { get; set; }
    public bool IsOperable { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DrawingReference> DrawingReferences { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SpecReference> SpecReferences { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SafetyRequirement> SafetyRequirements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SupportSystem> SupportSystems { get; set; }
}
```

The model for one the other table with a many to many.

```
public partial class SafetyRequirement : DataModel
    {
        [StringLength(256)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(2048)]
        public string SafetyFunction { get; set; }
        [StringLength(2048)]
        public string FunctionalRequirements { get; set; }
        [StringLength(2048)]
        public string SystemBoundary { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("QualityLevel")]
        public int QualityLevelId { get; set; }
        public virtual QualityLevel QualityLevel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
```

The map for the joining table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>().HasMany(t => t.SafetyRequirements)
    .WithMany(t => t.Assets)
    .Map(m =>
    {
       m.MapRightKey("SafetyRequirementId");
       m.MapLeftKey("AssetId");
       m.ToTable("AssetSafetyRequirement");
    });
```

Finally here's the area that it fails...

```
public virtual void SaveAsync(TEntity model)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (
            var dbContext =
                (TContext)
                Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (TContext),
                ConfigOptions == null ? ConfigService.ConnectionString : ConfigOptions.ConnectionString))
        {
            var dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
            dbSet.Attach(model);
            dbContext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    });
}
```

Any information or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use both Fluent API and Data Annotations to define the relationships between your tables. Remove one or the other.

Comment: This worked!  Took that out re ran my migration and it started to fall in place.